# Jar does not start while the same project in IDE does

Tags: java, spring, maven

There is little bit confusing situation. I cannot run jar file while in my IDE all works fine. By the way, only one module from whole project behaves this way.
So, there is my stacktrace

```
    [WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] referenced by given URL [file:/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication.main(SFDCGatewayApplication.java:97) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] referenced by given URL [file:/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] does not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.<init>(JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:55) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:48) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.buildArchiveDescriptor(AbstractScannerImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'assignInteractionContainer': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] referenced by given URL [file:/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication.main(SFDCGatewayApplication.java:97) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] referenced by given URL [file:/D:/temp/sfdc-gateway-1.0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes] does not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.<init>(JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:55) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:48) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.buildArchiveDescriptor(AbstractScannerImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

And there is my pom.xml build section:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
                </jvmArguments>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I'm 100% sure that these classes exists, there is a picture: [image]
Unfortunately, google didn't help me. So what is the reason?
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I cannot update spring boot higher than 1.2.5

ADDED: Manifest content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: beleych
Start-Class: com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.0.0.M6
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Comment: Can you add content on `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` ?

Comment: I have added, you can check

Comment: I'm confused, you said "I cannot update spring boot higher than 1.2.5" and there is `Spring-Boot-Version: 2.0.0.M6` ?!?

Comment: How are you running from cmd? Can you close your IDE and try to run it? Can you test in different folder? Btw I cannot see `Implementation-Version:` in MANIFEST. Can you temporay try to change version to 1.0.1 or something instead of 1.0.0.1.0 ?

Comment: Yeap, 2.0.0.M6 version is used only for plugin :) (not my decision) I will try all the things you adviced and answer. Thank you

Comment: 1. command `java -jar myJar.jar` 2. Tried to close IDE and start from different folders. 3. I removed useless maven-jar-plugin. 4. Tried to change version. The same result. Strange....

Comment: Please update the question also. Ok, so it is your code it seems, please provide the code for Start class, from stacktrace we see `at com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication.main(SFDCGatewayApplication.java:97)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

in a `Spring Boot` app? `Spring Boot` would probably do that with no extra plugin.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's redundant. But I tried without this plugin with the same negative result,

Comment: COuld you paste your pom.xml? As someone else asked, you said you cannot use Spring Boot higher than 1.2.5 but you are including 2.0.0.M6

Comment: I believe, that there should be only `<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>` plugin without configuration and rest should go at least to test it...

Comment: Spring Boot takes care of bundling all the dependencies in the jar app and sets the main class, it also takes care of extracting it, setting the classpath and start the app. I might be wrong since I haven't used maven-jar-plugin in a while, but I don;t think it would take care if bundling transitive dependencies.
Basically, if this is a Spring Boot app, rely on Spring Boot packaging

Comment: ...by go I meant "go away" = to be deleted from pom.xml, I see now it was not clear ;-) I agree with you I believe we are on a same page.

Answer (score 0):

From stacktrace it seems, you are trying to open it from your SFDCGatewayApplication class, important part of stacktrace (2nd row):

```
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.acme.ept.cra.gateway.sfdc.SFDCGatewayApplication.main(SFDCGatewayApplication.java:97) [classes!/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Thank you for help. Problem was in old version of hibernate.
Cause: **hibernate was looking for entities in jar** (but they were none and they shouldn't be there). In earlier versions of hibernate in this case it raised an error. In current version it raises only [WARN].
I want to say that error description is super unclear. So my solution is:

Add dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

And exclude this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to include / exclude dependencies, just add this version property with desired version: `<hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>`